# Program compiling and running, but not working?

Tags: c++

I had some problems with this code, got some help and it was working fine. Proceeded to do some tweaking and now the program compiles and runs, but it's not doing what it is supposed to do (take in a c++ file, remove the comments, and print out a new file). It is not printing out a new file...any ideas what I messed up?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

void remove_comments (ifstream& , ofstream&);

int main(void)
{
  int i;
  string inputFileName;
  string outputFileName;
  string s;
  ifstream fileIn;
  ofstream fileOut;
  char ch;

  do
  {
    cout<<"Enter the input file name:";
    cin>>inputFileName;
  }
  while (fileIn.fail() );
  cout<<"Enter the output file name: ";
  cin>>outputFileName;

  fileIn.open(inputFileName.data());
  assert(fileIn.is_open() );
  remove_comments ( fileIn , fileOut);         

  fileIn.close();
  fileOut.close();

  return 0;
}


void remove_comments( ifstream& fileIn , ofstream& fileOut)
{
  string line;
  bool flag = false;

  while (! fileIn.eof() )
  {

    getline(fileIn, line);

    if (line.find("/*") < line.length() )
      flag = true;
    if (! flag)
    {
      for (int i=0; i < line.length(); i++)
      {

        if(i<line.length())
          if ((line.at(i) == '/') && (line.at(i + 1) == '/'))
          break;
          else
            fileOut << line[i];
      }
      fileOut<<endl;


  }
  if(flag)
  {
    if(line.find("*/") < line.length() )
      flag = false;
  }

}
}
```

Comment: version control is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to open the output stream file using [`std::ofstream::open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open):

```
fileOut.open(outputFileName);
```

also notice that `std::ifstream` [has an overload for `open`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/open) that takes an `std::string` by constant reference, so:

```
fileIn.open(inputFileName.data());
```

can become:

```
 fileIn.open(inputFileName);
```

Comment: Wow...Such a simple mistake! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you get parameters from command line?

it would be much simple.

```
void remove_comments (ifstream& , ofstream&);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  if(argc!=3){
    cerr<<"usage: "<<argv[0]<<" input.file output.file\n";
    return -1;
  }
  int i;
  string inputFileName=argv[1];
  string outputFileName=argv[2];
  string s;
  ifstream fileIn(inputFileName.c_str());
  if(!fileIn.is_open()){
     cerr<<"error opening input file\n";
     return -1; 
  }
  ofstream fileOut(outputFileName.c_str());
  if(!fileOut.is_open()){
     cerr<<"error opening Output file\n";
     return -1; 
  }
  remove_comments ( fileIn , fileOut);       

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Asking user for input on console is a perfectly valid use case.

Comment: Yes. but it is not so user friendly. You don't have auto completion, you can't drag and drop, and you really have problem if the file is not in the current folder(very long input, easy to mistake), or have spaces in the file path(you just cant give it via `cin`).